# Inject different helper functions Angular

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to inject a few helpers (lodash and a few of my own) in Angular controllers so I have:

```
angular.module('app').factory("_", Lodash);
Lodash.$inject = ['$window'];
function Lodash($window) {
  if ($window._) 
    return $window._;
}

angular.module('app').factory("_", Helper);
Helper.$inject = ['$window']; 
function Helper($window) {  
  return {
    test: function () {
      return "test";
    }
  }
}
```

So I would like all helpers to be accessible under _ and I would define them in a few JS files ... Can this be done?

With my code only one of them work: lodash methods or test().

Comment: beacuse both of your factories have the same name..

Comment: yes, I know ... my question is if I can merge the methods in lodash and my own in the same factory accessible in _

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For services that don't require dependencies (`$window` isn't crucial here because it serves for no purpose and can be replaced with `window` or `_` global) `config` block is a good place to define them, because `constant` services are already available there.

```
app.config(function ($injector, $provide) {
  var lodash = $injector.has('_') ? $injector.get('_') : {};
  angular.extend(lodash, window._);
  $provide.constant('_', lodash);
});

app.config(function ($injector, $provide) {
  var lodash = $injector.has('_') ? $injector.get('_') : {};
  angular.extend(lodash, {
    test: ...
  });
  $provide.constant('_', lodash);
});
```

When the service is defined this way, its value can be extended several times, the order of `config` blocks doesn't matter.

Alternatively, service value [can be changed with decorator](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/angular.Module#decorator), in order to do that the service should be already defined.

Answer (score 0):

You can not redeclare a factory. As you already noticed, this will overwrite the previous.

You could prepare the helper in separate files and register them in one factory call elsewhere in your app.

Comment: Yes, that is my idea ... To merge lodash methods with my own methods under _ factory. But how can I do that? Could you give an example with the code I posted?